# Chain rule proof assumption.

Tags: calculus

I am reading this in my text:

[image]

I have 3 questions:

1. What is $\epsilon$.
2. "If we define $\epsilon$ to be 0 when x is 0, then $\epsilon$ becomes a continuous function of x."  Why is this true? I don't see it.
3. Why is $\Delta{y} = f'(a) \Delta{x} + \epsilon \Delta{x} $ ? Isn't the change in y just = $f'(a) \epsilon{x}$?

Comment: "So if we denote $\epsilon$ the difference quotient and the derivative"  SO $\epsilon =\frac {\triangle y}{\triangle x} - f'(a)$

Comment: Another question on the same proof: [Chain rule proof is a bit unclear. What is epsilion in this proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2621170/139123)

Answer (score 1):

1. The answer is in the text: $\varepsilon$ is *by definition* the difference $$\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-f^\prime(a)$$ Note that this makes $\varepsilon$ a function of $\Delta x$, in particular (in the same way as $f(x)=\dfrac{2}{x}-3$ is a continuous function of $x$ away from $x=0$).
2. Note that the above assumption makes no sense when $\Delta x=0$. Therefore you need a separate definition in that case. But one choice is better than all others because it will make $\varepsilon$ a *continuous* function of $\Delta x$.
3. This is simply rewriting the definition of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: simple rewrites are confusing sometimes because now I'm trying to make sense of the new equation. Why would $\epsilon$ be a continuous function of $\Delta{x}$? What does this mean? can you flesh it out a bit?

Comment: When you write $f(x)=\frac2x$, $f$ is a continuous function of $x$ right?
Here $\varepsilon=\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$, different notations, same thing.

Comment: f is continuous? What if x = 0?

Comment: That's Point 2. In the present case, when $\Delta x$ tends to $0$, $\varepsilon$ tends to $0$ as well, therefore there is a continuous extension by setting $\varepsilon=0$ when $\Delta x=0$. This is not the case in the analogy that I made with $\frac2x$.

Answer (score 1):

1) $\epsilon =\frac {\triangle y}{\triangle x} - f'(a)$.

This is a value dependent upon $\triangle x$ and $\triangle y$.  $\triangle y$ is dependent up $\triangle x$.  So we can think of $\epsilon$ as a function of $\triangle x$.

IMO, I'd find it clearer if we wrote $\epsilon$ as $\epsilon_{\triangle x}$ or as $\epsilon(\triangle x)$.  But this text didn't.  Oh, well.

Notice: $\epsilon_{\triangle x}$ is undefined at $\triangle x = 0$.

And notice $\lim_{\triangle x\to 0} \epsilon_{\triangle x}=\lim_{\triangle x\to 0} (\frac {\triangle y}{\triangle x} - f'(a))=0$.

2) A function $g(x)$ is continuous and $x = a$ if $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = g(a)$.  That's practically the definition of continuous.

So we define $\epsilon_{\triangle x}$ as:  if $\triangle x \ne 0$ then $\epsilon_{\triangle x}=\frac {\triangle y}{\triangle x} - f'(a)$; if $\triangle x = 0$ then $\epsilon_{\triangle x}=0$.

Now $\lim_{\triangle x\to 0} \epsilon_{\triangle x}=\lim_{\triangle x\to 0} (\frac {\triangle y}{\triangle x} - f'(a))=0 = \epsilon_0$.

So $\epsilon_{\triangle x}$ is a continuous function at $\triangle x = 0$

3)  "Why is Δy=f′(a)Δx+ϵΔx ? Isn't the change in y just = f′(a)ϵx?"

No, because $\epsilon$ is not a constant.

$\epsilon = \frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x} - f'(a)$ so

$\epsilon \Delta x = \Delta y - f'(a)\Delta x$

$\Delta y = f'(a)\Delta x + \epsilon \Delta x$.

This, however, is differentiable because $\epsilon$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Is there a typo here: " g(x)g(x) is continuous and x=ax=a if limx→af(x)=f(a)limx→af(x)=f(a). That's practically the definition of continuous."

Comment: Argh... I chose g to not confuse it with the f in the proof.  And then I forgot.  Argh.