# Ambiguity in chaine rule calculus

Tags: calculus

[image]

Okay but what is the need to make epsilon continuous at delta x =0 ? We could do the proof without that.

Comment: For reference, the same proof from the same textbook appears to be the subject of the question [Chain rule proof assumption.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2631397/139123) That question asks how it is possible that $\varepsilon$ **can** be continuous at $\Delta x =0,$ here it is asked why $\varepsilon$ **must** be continuous.

Comment: Another question on the same proof: [Chain rule proof is a bit unclear. What is epsilion in this proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2621170/139123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if $g$ is a constant function, for example, $g(x) = 2?$
Then no matter what increment you take in $\Delta x,$
you will always find that $\Delta u = 0.$
If $\varepsilon_2$ were not defined when $\Delta u = 0,$
the right-hand side of Equation $9$ would not be defined for any $\Delta x,$
and you wouldn't be able to continue the proof after that point.

But the Chain Rule is still valid even if one of the functions is constant.
Continuing the example above, if $a = 0$ then $g(a) = 2$ and $g'(a) = 0,$
so (provided that $f$ is differentiable at $2$),

$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(a)) g'(a) = f'(2) \cdot 0 = 0, $$

which is a correct result.

Comment: Thank very much . I asked this question before but the answers i got had nothing to do with the question. So i reposted it and gladly this time you cleared things for me.